# Use of thread is not working properly

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am making an app using aide app,when using  thread in it & install it then the smart manager of Samsung device shows that the app contains malware.

My codes are for **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.mycompany.staticgk;

import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.os.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Intent i = new Intent(this,SplashActivity.class);

        Thread timer= new Thread (){

            public void run(){

                try {
                    try
                    {
                        sleep(3000);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                finally {
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

while for **SplashActivity.java**

```
package com.mycompany.staticgk;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
    }
}
```

**Please**,correct me if anywhere i am wrong.

Comment: what not working properly? please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Is not error on your code.its security based problem .dont install apk with unauthorized app they may be hack your phone informations

> Best Use Android Studio [The official Android IDE] to develope code and generate apk with signature key then only
>   mobile allows to install apk on device.All the native app are developed through android studio only.

otherwise enable Unknown source in your device it may be install on device.

```
Settings>>Lock screen and security>> tap on toggle button of Unknown Sources.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to go to `MainActivity` from `SplashActivity` one way could be :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.class,SplashActivity.class););
            finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }).start();
```

Also I see something weird with that double `try catch block` put just one.

Happy coding

Comment: he did: `timer.start();`